# Qt Custom Widget Plugin Q_Property With Q_ENUM

Tags: c++17, qt-designer, qt6

In my custom designer widget plugin I have a custom widget that derives QWidget. I have a "shape" field to choose the widget shape itself: Circle, Square, Triangle, Rounded. For this I have simply made an enum "ledShape" with the four shapes. I would like to use these values in the QtDesigner widget property area via implementing a Q_PROPERTY macro.
The code I wrote produces a QComboBox in the QtDesigner property editor with the four shapes.

This code produces a QComboBox in the QtDesigner property editor with the four shapes:
QNewLed.h

```
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtUiPlugin/QDesignerExportWidget>
#include <QtSvg>
#include <QSvgRenderer>

class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT QNewLed : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(ledShape shape READ getShape WRITE setShape)

public:
    explicit QNewLed(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~QNewLed();

    enum ledShape { Circle, Square, Triangle, Rounded };
    Q_ENUM(ledShape)

public slots:
    ledShape getShape() const { return m_shape; }
    void setShape(ledShape);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;
    ledShape m_shape;
    QStringList m_shapes;

private:
    QSvgRenderer* renderer;
};
```

QNewLed.cpp

```
#include "QNewLed.h"

QNewLed::QNewLed(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), m_shape(Rounded)
{
    m_shapes << ":/resources/circle_green.svg" << ":/resources/square_orange.svg" << ":/resources/triang_blue.svg" << ":/resources/round_yellow.svg";
    setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 50));
    renderer = new QSvgRenderer();
}

QNewLed::~QNewLed()
{
    delete renderer;
}

void QNewLed::setShape(ledShape newShape)
{
    m_shape = newShape;
    
    update();
}

void QNewLed::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    QPainter painter(this);

    QString ledShapeAndColor;
    ledShapeAndColor = m_shapes[m_shape];

    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    renderer->load(ledShapeAndColor);
    renderer->render(&painter);
}
```

Now I insert my widget to create an application that displays the image of the widget itself (a led with the chosen shape) in QtDesigner. Then I go to the properties panel of QNewLed (my widget) and in the "shape" property I select Triangle. This value is not kept, but reverts to the first one, which is Circle. How do I get Triangle to be set instead ?